# Pygame - Moving Sprites at Different Speeds

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on the mechanics of several sprites i am using. I am working on game that involves collecting coins. I have sprite image of a spinning coin. I created a class for the coin sprite and I wrote an update function which switches from one image sprite to the next. The coin is spinning but the problem I'm having is that it is spinning too fast. How can i slow dow the spinning of the coin? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the coin class:

```
class coins (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
coin_spin_frames = []
def __init__(self, x, y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('stuff/coins_1.png')

    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 42)
    self.coin_spin_frames.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 42, 40, 42)
    self.coin_spin_frames.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 84, 40, 42)
    self.coin_spin_frames.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 130, 40, 42)
    self.coin_spin_frames.append(image)

    self.image = self.coin_spin_frames[0]

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
def update(self):
    if self.image == self.coin_spin_frames[0]:
        self.image = self.coin_spin_frames[1]
    elif self.image == self.coin_spin_frames[1]:
        self.image = self.coin_spin_frames[2]
    elif self.image == self.coin_spin_frames[2]:
        self.image = self.coin_spin_frames[3]
    elif self.image == self.coin_spin_frames[3]:
        self.image = self.coin_spin_frames[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, determine how fast you want the coin to spin. Let's say you want it to take 2 seconds to make a complete loop.

The update() function can call time.time(), and mod it by the amount of time to make a loop, then divide that by the loop time. (123121213.2 % 2 = 1.2. 1.2 / 2 = 0.6). Now, display the image that is 60% of the way through the self.coin_spin_frames list. (int(len(self.coin_spin_frames) * 0.6))

Comment: This is making sense to me, but i don't quite understand the last line of your response, can you possible expand on what your saying. Thank you.

Comment: The general idea is that if you want to loop through the frames in 2 seconds, and there are 10 frames, each frame should be displayed for 0.2 seconds. This says that you are 1.2s into a 2s loop, and so should be displaying the 6th frame. The calculation given is to find the index in self.coin_spin_frames that should be displayed. (I might have an off-by-one error in there.)

Comment: I understand that now. thank you. Now I'm trying to get it to work but i can't call time.time()

Comment: Did you remember to import time?